# SP2013 column validation error message issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, form, document-set, validation

I'm using on-premise Sharepoint Server 2013 and within my site collection I need to apply field validation formula to document library using document set content type. In case formula is used for plain document library (no document set content type) it works OK and error message is displayed below the field on new document entry form. When using document set content type, in case adding new set of documents the same validation formula shows its error message on separate page like below... (local language version hence some translations)

[image]

This ends adding new set of documents and makes user to fill in all fields from scratch... in short, this is not very handy. So here is my question: how to make validation formula display its error messages on new document entry form in case new document set is created in the library?

Thanks in advance for any idea or advice!

Comment: What was logged in ULS with that correlation ID?